# tuple from argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I wrote a remote call procedure wrapper..
On server-side I have some human-readable interface, for example:

```
template<typename TBase>
class LogicUnit : TBase
{
public:
  int getLenFromCalculate(
    double antenaForce, const std::string & duration) IMPLEMENTATION;

  float calcSomeAlse(
    int tableW, float integral) IMPLEMENTATION;
};
```

From client-side I want use it like this:

```
#define IMPLEMENTATION TUPLE_FROM_ARGS
#include "logicUnit.h"
#undef 

LogicUnit<ClientNetwork> logicUnit;
logicUnit.connect("10.123.123.123", "8080");
logicUnit.getLenFromCalculate( 20.032, "faster" );
```

In `ClientNetwork` I have a helper function:

```
template< typename ... Args >
bool send( const std::string & funcName, std::tuple<Args...> tuple );
```

And my question - what can I write in TUPLE_FROM_ARGS-macros? I want something like the following:

```
define TUPLE_FROM_ARGS send( __FUNCTION__, std::make_tuple( ??????? ) );
```

Or how I can resolve my problem another way?
In this library http://code.google.com/p/simple-rpc-cpp/
used script-generator for create IMPLEMENTATION code. But I think, is it possible by using templates and macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for a variadic macro:

```
#define TUPLE_FROM_ARGS( ... ) \
    send( __FUNCTION__, std::make_tuple( __VA_ARGS__ ) );
```

---

It's hard to give good advice if you are so unclear about what you really need. Learn to write good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)'s. Anyways, maybe you are looking for this:

```
template< typename... Args >
int getLenFromCalculate( Args&&... args )
{
    send( __FUNCTION__, std::make_tuple( std::forward< Args >( args )... ) );
}
```

(In the above I don't really see the need for the macro anymore)

Comment: and for each function I mast copy-paste arg-list?

Comment: like 
int getLenFromCalculate( double antenaForce, const std::string & duration)
{
   TUPLE_FROM_ARGS( antenaForce, duration );
}

float calcSomeAlse( int tableW, float integral)
{
   TUPLE_FROM_ARGS( tableW, integral);
}

e.t.c.

it's uogly looking, I thing. For do this, I mast write script for code generator, e.g. just use http://code.google.com/p/simple-rpc-cpp.

Answer (score 0):

-- continues my question --

I have definition of class member:

```
class LogicUnit
{
public:
  RPC_FUNC_BEGIN
      int getLenFromCalculate(double antenaForce, const std::string & duration);
  RPC_FUNC_END
};
```

On the client-side, it mast be some Implementation, on the server-side, it mast be some another Implementation. For example:

```
// LogicUnit_c.h
int LogicUnit::getLenFromCalculate( double _1, const std::string & _2 )
{
    return send(__COUNTER__, _1, _2);
}

// LogicUnit_s.h
int LogicUnit::getLenFromCalculate( double antenaForce, const std::string & duration )
{
   return (int)(duration.length() * antenaForce);
}
```

If I have many members, I mast write next look-as-template code:

```
int Foo::fooBar( double _1, int _2 ) { return send(__COUNTER__, _1, _2); }
void Foo::someQwe( double _1, int _2 ) { return send(__COUNTER__, _1, _2); }
int Foo::getParam( const std::string & _1 ) { return send(__COUNTER__, _1); }
void Foo::beNext( int _1, float _2, SMyStruct _3 ) { return send(__COUNTER__, _1, _2, _3); }
```

I need `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and something like that:
[How to get function signature via preprocessor define written before it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729168/how-to-get-function-signature-via-preprocessor-define-writen-before-it)